# Why is the Lorentz invariant integration measure for a spinor $\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{m}{\omega}$?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, spinors, invariants

I understand for a scalar field theory the integration measure is $\frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\omega}$ because it has to satisfy the following equation
$$\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\delta(\omega^2-|\vec{k}|^2-m^2)\theta(\omega)\Phi(x,k)$$
Such that it is always on shell and has positive energies. Is there an equivalent formulation to derive the spinor version of the integration measure such that

$$\sum_s \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}f(\omega)\Phi_s(x,k)$$

Where
$$f(\omega)=\frac{m}{\omega}$$
$$\Phi(x,k)=a_s(k)u_s(k)e^{-ik\cdot x}+b^\dagger_s(k)v_s(k)e^{ik\cdot x}$$
Im learning basic QFT from
Dietterich Labs, the specific video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8GUJ6gyvoc&t=1002s
Can anyone explain where the factor comes from?

Comment: Given that $m$ and $2$ are scalars, the two measures are proportional. The same proof as in the scalar case should work, shouldn't it? Do you have a reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Javier The reason I thought it was different for spinnors is because the guy that I'm learning from has used one convention for scalar fields and another for fermionic fields

Comment: @Javier Would that also mean that I could also have a factor $\frac{a}{2\omega}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2\omega}$ because $a$ is a scalar?

Comment: There is some ambiguity here. It seems that $m$ is a mass in the first equation. Is it still a mass or does it become a numeric constant in the third expression?

Comment: @flippiefanus m is still the mass